# Multithreading a code using System.Reactive's extensions

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive, .net-5

The code below downloads historical OHLCV data from Binance from a start date to an end date. Since Binance allows us to download only 1000 candles at a time, I did `DownloadAsync` the way it is. Any recommendations onto the code, are appreciated as well.

The actual question is about making `DownloadAsync` multithreaded, in order to speed up the process, because imagine downloading candles from 2018 to 2021 on 5m interval. I would prefer using `System.Reactive`, but I guess other solutions are welcome too, since it's hard to represent the code to a multithreading version.

The code below can be tested.

```cs
using Binance.Net;
using Binance.Net.Enums;
using Binance.Net.Interfaces;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace DownloadCandleDataTest
{
    public class DataProvider
    {
        private Exchange _exchange;

        public DataProvider(Exchange exchange)
        {
            _exchange = exchange;
        }

        public async Task<List<OHLCV>> DownloadAsync(string pair, KlineInterval interval, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int startupCandleCount)
        {
            DateTime start = startDate;
            DateTime end = endDate;

            var tempStartDate = start;
            var tempEndDate = end;
            var tempList = new List<OHLCV>();

            for (int i = 0; tempStartDate < tempEndDate; i++)
            {
                var candles = await _exchange.GetCandlesAsync(pair, interval, tempStartDate, tempEndDate, 100).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (candles.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Remove the first candle when i > 0, to prevent duplicates
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        candles.RemoveAt(0);
                    }

                    var first = candles.First();
                    var last = candles.Last();
                    Console.WriteLine($"First: {first.Timestamp} | Last: {last.Timestamp}");

                    tempList.AddRange(candles);

                    tempStartDate = last.Timestamp;
                }
            }

            // Find duplicates
            var groups = tempList.GroupBy(g => g.Timestamp).Where(e => e.Skip(1).Any());

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
                foreach (var ohclv in group)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + ohclv.Timestamp);
                }
            }


            return null;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void StartBackgroundWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Shows use of Start to start on a background thread:");
            var o = Observable.Start(() =>
            {
                //This starts on a background thread.
                Console.WriteLine("From background thread. Does not block main thread.");
                Console.WriteLine("Calculating...");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                Console.WriteLine("Background work completed.");
            }).Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("Main thread completed."));
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n\t In Main Thread...\r\n");
            o.Wait();   // Wait for completion of background operation.
        }

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var exchange = new Exchange();
            var dataProvider = new DataProvider(exchange);
            await dataProvider.DownloadAsync("TRXUSDT", KlineInterval.FiveMinutes, new DateTime(2019, 1, 1), new DateTime(2019, 1, 2), 100).ConfigureAwait(false);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class OHLCV
    {
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public decimal Open { get; set; }
        public decimal High { get; set; }
        public decimal Low { get; set; }
        public decimal Close { get; set; }
        public decimal Volume { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static OHLCV ToCandle(this IBinanceKline candle)
        {
            return new OHLCV
            {
                Timestamp = candle.OpenTime,
                Open = candle.Open,
                High = candle.High,
                Low = candle.Low,
                Close = candle.Close,
                Volume = candle.BaseVolume,
            };
        }
    }

    public class Exchange : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IBinanceClient _client;

        public Exchange()
        {
            _client = new BinanceClient();
        }

        public async Task<List<OHLCV>> GetCandlesAsync(string pair, KlineInterval interval, DateTime? startTime = null, DateTime? endTime = null, int? limit = null)
        {
            var result = await _client.Spot.Market.GetKlinesAsync(pair, interval, startTime, endTime, limit).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (result.Success)
            {
                return result.Data?.Select(e => e.ToCandle()).ToList();
            }

            return null;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_client != null)
            {
                _client.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual question, do you want to do more downloads in parallel?  Does the processing after downloading take CPU time and you want to parallelise it?

Comment: I want more downloads in parallel, yes. In Python (ccxt), it downloads the candles so fast, because of the multithreading. Python (ccxt lib) uses asyncio. https://github.com/freqtrade/freqtrade/blob/cd41d11b850251036e398faef19e8cdd7d572256/freqtrade/exchange/exchange.py#L723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seriously overthinking this.

Since you're getting evenly spaced candles and you know how many you get per call to `GetKlinesAsync` you can compute all of the start dates required.

```
    var pair = "TRXUSDT";
    var interval = KlineInterval.FiveMinutes;
    var startDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1);
    var endDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 2);
    var gap = 5.0; // same as `interval` for purpose of computing start dates.
    var limit = 100;

    IObservable<DateTime> startDates =
        Observable
            .Generate(startDate, x => x <= endDate, x => x.AddMinutes(gap * limit), x => x);
```

Now it's quite easy to generate your query:

```
    IObservable<OHLCV> query =
        from s in startDates
        from rs in
            Observable
                .Using(
                    () => new BinanceClient(),
                    bc => Observable.FromAsync(ct =>
                        bc.Spot.Market.GetKlinesAsync(pair, interval, s, endDate, limit, ct)))
        where rs.Success
        from c in rs.Data.Select(x => x.ToCandle())
        select c;
```

Since this is querying in parallel it is possible, even likely, that you'll get your results out of order, so you need to do a `.ToArray()` on the query to be able to deal with all of the data produced at the end, rather than as each candle comes in.

```
    IDisposable subscription =
        query
            .ToArray()
            .Select(xs => xs.OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp).ToArray())
            .Subscribe(cs =>
            {
                /* candles downloaded using multiple threads */
                /* and sorted in `Timestamp` order  */
            });
```

This produces all of the candles, in order, using multiple threads, without any duplicates.

If you want it as the `DownLoadAsync` method then you do this:

```
public async Task<List<OHLCV>> DownloadAsync(string pair, KlineInterval interval, double gap, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int limit)
{
    IObservable<DateTime> startDates =
        Observable
            .Generate(startDate, x => x <= endDate, x => x.AddMinutes(gap * limit), x => x);

    IObservable<OHLCV> query =
        from s in startDates
        from rs in
            Observable
                .Using(
                    () => new BinanceClient(),
                    bc => Observable.FromAsync(ct =>
                        bc.Spot.Market.GetKlinesAsync(pair, interval, s, endDate, limit, ct)))
        where rs.Success
        from c in rs.Data.Select(x => x.ToCandle())
        select c;

    return await query.ToArray().Select(xs => xs.OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp).ToList());
}
```

Note that the signature has changed slightly.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! How do I return the candles to the DownloadAsync method?

Comment: @nop - It's fairly trivial to do want you want, just await the single value observable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I wanted.

Comment: `IObservable<OHLCV> query =
 from s in startDates
 from rs in
  Observable.FromAsync(ct => _exchange.GetCandlesAsync(pair, interval, s, endDate, limit, ct))
 from c in rs.Select(x => x)
 select c;`. I wanted to use my GetCandlesAsync method instead of creating a new BinanceClient everytime. Is my example correct? Better view here: https://pastebin.com/DWV3W9Yh. Basically I removed `Observable.Using`

Comment: by downloading data from 2019-1-1 to 2020-1-2, it has 352 duplicates https://i.imgur.com/HvuCiC4.png. Code here: https://pastebin.com/ibg5tSJr

Comment: I changed it to `return await query.ToArray().Select(xs => xs.DistinctBy(e => e.Timestamp).OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp).ToList());` using MoreLinq, but if you know why these duplicates were presented, let me know, mate

Comment: @nop - I didn't get duplicates in my original testing. Can you please provide a [mcve] in your question - that I can copy, paste, and run - to see your duplicates? I should be able to set up a simple Console app to run it.

Comment: here is full code: https://pastebin.com/6XacWHnB. You can run the code. It will download the data using Binance.Net package. The wrong candles.Count is 105509 (including the duplicates). It's supposed to be 105517 and the dictionary `duplicates` to be empty. Right now it has 352 duplicates. If I use DistinctBy from MoreLinq, it removes the duplicates, but it would be better to fix the code to not return those duplicates at all.

Comment: @nop - The source Binance data is missing records. For example, there are no records for the times `2019/03/12 02:00` & `2019/03/12 07:55` inclusive. The call to `GetCandlesAsync` is always returning 1,000 records so it's doubling up on some records. It should be a relatively simple matter of computing the end date too.

Comment: @nop - Or, in full, this: https://pastebin.com/4GuNavFc

Comment: thanks a lot mate! It works! Is `Observable.Using(() => new BinanceClient` important? I mean, can I use the class I made above `ExchangeApi.GetCandlesAsync`.

Comment: @nop - The class you made it an overhead that potentially just adds bugs. And since it implements `IDisposable` you should then use `Observable.Using` anyway. THe number one predictor for bugs is code. The more code you write the more bugs you have. So write less code.

Comment: That class is because I have many other methods in my real project. It doesn't only have GetCandlesAsync, but thanks, I got the idea!

Comment: @nop - Push the `Observable.Using` into each method. Disposable resources generally shouldn't hang around.

Comment: can't I just dispose the entire `DataProvider` class in the end, instead?

Comment: @nop - You can do anything you like, but I try to write less code and I try to create and dispose disposable resources as quickly as I can.

Answer (score 0):

The key to make more web requests in parallel is to create many tasks and to await them all with `Task.WhenAll()` instead of awaiting each one inside the loop(s).

If you await each one in a loop they will be processed sequentially (though the UI thread will not be blocked whilst the web request is made).

Comment: I know the concept. I need a snippet with my DownloadAsync method, because look at it. Even a Parallel.For can't be used on it right now